# permission ERROR but ask, httpurlconnection android

Tags: android, request, httpurlconnection, permission-denied

I am currently coding an android app, and I ve got an issue in my POST request to contact an API host on a server.

here is the code where it crash:

```
    String url = "http://my_api/some_route";
    URL urlObj = null;
    urlObj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
    connect.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());   // <- ERROR HERE
    out.write(params.toString());
    out.close();
```

Where params variable represent a JSONObject

my manifest file contain:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

After many many search on the internet I have tried the others way to ask the internet permission same result

here is my error (the Cause by line):

```
   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

If anyone have any clue or some documentation where I can find the way

PS: I am very new at android maybe my coding style on those line are not at the norm

Comment: Other than the INTERNET permission, do you also have these - android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" and 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"?

Comment: @ADimaano I ve just tried same error

Comment: Have you kept the `<uses-permission>` inside the `<application>` tag??

Comment: @GradleDroid yes

Answer (score 0):

The `<uses-permission>` should be kept **outside** the `<application>` tag.

Like this..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dea600"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/example"
        android:label="@string/appName" >

.....
```

Please update it and try.